# How to quited the git bash when Re-direct as output？

Tags: c

Today I have the  problem about how to quit the git bash input.
The book wrote press Ctrl+D(UNIX) or Ctrl+Z(DOS) in the new line.

I try it but failed.

[image]

[image]

So I just ask the command to quit it.

Comment: is the question about the shell or your program? did you try ctrl-c to kill your program and/or tying "exit" to exit the shell?

Comment: It seems you have a problem quitting your program and not the shell. Also [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is written so that it quits when you enter '#' into the terminal. It cannot detect end of file because that would require a different condition. (You would have to test for EOF, and in addition declare the variable `ch` as `int` because that is the actual return value from `getchar()` and because `EOF` is usually defined as -1.)